# knockout validation subscribe update after change

Tags: validation, knockout.js, subscribe

I have model 'search Parameters', which has two properties title and priceMax,both are required. When user change properties, script update quantity of offers from API.  Update is execute, when model 'searchParameters' hasn't errors. Problem is in metodh, which return count errors in model. When title and priceMax have value,  method return errors, only when I change property of model again method return value 0. Any idea? This is my solution.

> HTML

```
   <fieldset>
      <div class="row">
        <label>Title:</label>
        <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: searchParameters.title" />

      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <label>Price max:</label>
        <input data-bind="textInput: searchParameters.priceMax" />

      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label>count offers:</label>
        <span data-bind="text: countOffers"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row" data-bind="visible:visibleProgress">
        progress...
      </div>
    </fieldset>
```

> JS

```
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.countOffers = ko.observable(0);
  self.visibleProgress = ko.observable(false);
  ko.extenders.refreshCountOffers = function(target, timeout) {
    var timerId = null;
    target.subscribe(function(newValue) {
      console.log(self.errors());
      if (self.errors().length === 0) {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        timerId = setTimeout(function() {
          self.visibleProgress(true);
          //mock api
          $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/js/?js=' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)),
            data: {
              delay: 2
            },
            complete: function(response) {
              self.countOffers(response.responseText);
              self.visibleProgress(false);
            }
          });
          //mock api
        }, 500);
      } else
        self.countOffers(0);
    });
    return target;
  };
  self.searchParameters = {
    title: ko.observable().extend({
      refreshCountOffers: 500
    }).extend({
      required: true
    }),
    priceMax: ko.observable().extend({
      refreshCountOffers: 500
    }).extend({
      required: true
    })
  };
  self.errors = ko.validation.group(self.searchParameters);
};

var model = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/llukaszz92/0vcmsk0c/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the order in which you are applying your extenders.  When you extend an observable, each extender is run in serial on the result of the previous one.

Your code therefore extends the *original* observable (where it subscribes to changes) and then the observable is extended again to make it required.

To be honest I am not 100% sure what `knockout-validation` is doing to the source observable that is causing the behaviour you see but if you reverse the order of your extenders (as in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9g73efn/1/)) then you guarantee that your custom extender will operate on the 'final' observable and will therefore work as you expect.

```
self.user = {
  firstName: ko.observable().extend({
    required: true,
    refreshCountOffers: 500
  }),
  lastName: ko.observable().extend({
    required: true,
    refreshCountOffers: 500
  })
};
```